# C++ expression must have class type error

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a database using my own implementation of linked list (called booklist) and I created a Book class for my implementation. The function below belongs to a class called BookDatabase which is using Book and BookList class. At my if statement, I get the error expression must have class type. Here is the code. books is a BookList used in BookDatabase class and getBookISBN is a function of Book Class. find function returns a Book object in a BookList's specified index.

```
void BookDatabase::removeBook(const string bookISBN){
    bool matchup = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < books.getLength() && !matchup; i++){
        if (bookISBN == ((books.find(i)).getbookISBN()){
            books.remove(i);
            matchup = true;
        }
    }    

    if (!matchup) {
        cout << "No matchup found" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of member function find.

Comment: Did you try declaring `const std::string bookISBN`?

Comment: Is `books` defined anywhere? "own implementation of linked list" sounds dangerous, `std::list` is usually what you need.

Comment: You need to create a [testcase](http://sscce.org), debug with it, then come back if you're still stuck.

Comment: Note: Searching inside linked list is ineffective, you should use `std::map` (or `std::unorderded_map` if C++11 is available ) to store books (or indices).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bookISBN == ((books.find(i)).getbookISBN()){
```

This line is worrisome. If its not compiling, its probably because books.find(i) isnt returning a correct type.

Also, find is a strange name for a numerical index lookup. (by the code, what your doing here is essentially array-style indexing). Also, if find is O(N), whichis likely with a list, then then this codeis O(N^2), which would be really really bad.